# Xamarin/Android app: Broadcast receiver not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to display a notification when an outgoing call is made, but it does not work (nothing is displayed). i tested the notification separately, it works fine, but am pretty sure I did something wrong in the BroadcastReceiver. 
Thanks in advance!

MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "ExamProject", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        MyBroadcastRecieverClass reciever;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        reciever = new MyBroadcastRecieverClass();
        RegisterReceiver(reciever, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"));
```

BroadcastReciever Class:

```
namespace App3
{
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall })]
public class MyBroadcastRecieverClass: BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Do stuff here.

        //String value = intent.GetStringExtra("key");

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context)
              .SetContentTitle("Test Title")
              .SetContentText("test content")
              .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
              .SetPriority(100)
              .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
              .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public)
              .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryAlarm);


        //build the notification
        Notification test = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;//should be changed to generate a uniqe value
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, test);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you add permissions to process outgoing phone calls? (`PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, there was a syntaxt problem here:

```
RegisterReceiver(reciever, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"));
```

Correct code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        MyBroadcastRecieverClass reciever;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        reciever = new MyBroadcastRecieverClass();

        IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        RegisterReceiver(reciever, myIntentFilter);

        Button settingsButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.settingsButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors in the *logcat* logs?

Make sure that you add the *PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS* permission to you project.

You must hold the [PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) permission to receive this Intent.

Comment: The permission is set so that is not the cause. Not sure which logs you are referring to, there is a lot of info in the debug output log in Visual Studio but I dont see anything that refers to the broadcast receiver